Hardware Performance Tool
We are seeking input on some automated (even a spreadsheet or Python) tool that we can enter preferred performance measures for hardware and then enter performance parameters of various hardware configurations and have the tool automatically list/show the most apporpriate/best one.
I hope I asked that clearly (probably like mud).

It sounds like your asking for Mouser.com
